# xUnit - What is the maximum number of parallel tests that can run in xUnit?

Tags: xunit, xunit2

xUnit documentation does not specify any limits on the number of parallel tests - https://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-parallel.html

Answer (score 1):

See the "Changing Default Behavior" section on [that page](https://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-parallel.html).

> Default: number of virtual CPUs in the PC

Comment: broken link, probably this is the new one https://xunit.net/docs/running-tests-in-parallel